# How can i filter with key date from key value object in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Item :

[image]

Mapping:

[image]

Can I do

```
if key == "date" and value  < 2021-08-28 15:43:58 OR > 2021-08-28 15:43:58
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't because the attr field needs to be nested type in order to match both criteria in the same attr object. Change the attrs mapping to nested type and use a nested query together with a bool query with the predicates you want to use.

But still then, you won't be able to query for larger or smaller dates because the attr.value is of type keyword. Consider using a date typed nested field (attrs.datevalue) for date values. And then maybe other typed value fields for future usage.

Comment: Maybe open a separate json column for each data type ty for reply

Comment: Yes, in such cases i have a textvalue (keyword), numbervalue (double), boolvalue and datvalue together with the key field. Then I am able to do nested queries anf filter on the specific field.